# Passing Js Variables into Datatables Columns

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, datatables

> I connect with php to my api where i get my datas converting it to
>   json passing it to javascript parsing it and then i want to use this datas in 
>   my columns in datatables but i have no idea also after reading many
>   threads and documentations how to do it can someone pls helpe me how
>   to do that?

```js
function updateLiveGateWayAll_SQL_UPDATE(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'gateWay_LIVE_UPDATE.php',
        success: (data) => {
            updateLiveGateWayAll_SQL_UPDATE_UNDER(data);
        }
    })
}

function updateLiveGateWayAll_SQL_UPDATE_UNDER(data){
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);

   var GATEWAY1_QUE = obj[0].QUE;
   var GATEWAY1_FAILED = obj[0].FAILED;
   var GATEWAY1_TOTAL = obj[0].TOTAL;
   var GATEWAY1_STATE = obj[0].STATE;

    var GATEWAY2_QUE = obj[1].QUE;
    var GATEWAY2_FAILED = obj[1].FAILED;
    var GATEWAY2_TOTAL = obj[1].TOTAL;
    var GATEWAY2_STATE = obj[1].STATE;

    var GATEWAY3_QUE = obj[2].QUE;
    var GATEWAY3_FAILED = obj[2].FAILED;
    var GATEWAY3_TOTAL = obj[2].TOTAL;
    var GATEWAY3_STATE = obj[2].STATE;

    var GATEWAY4_QUE = obj[3].QUE;
    var GATEWAY4_FAILED = obj[3].FAILED;
    var GATEWAY4_TOTAL = obj[3].TOTAL;
    var GATEWAY4_STATE = obj[3].STATE;


}



function updateHistoryGateWayALL_SQL_INSERT(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'gateWay_HISTORY_INSERT.php',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GATEWAY - INFO - TABLE</title>
    <!--Schritt_1: Link Style einbinden-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <!--Mein eigenes CSS um DataTables CSS zu überschreiben-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_Live_AND_History.css">
    <!--Schritt_2: jQuery Google einbinden-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--liveTimelinGateWayAll UND historyTimelineGateWayAll-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <!--Schritt_3: cdn dataTables einbinden-->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!--Schritt 4: Eigene JS einbinden (Optional)-->
    <script src="dataTable.js"></script>
    <!--historyTimelineGateWayAll-->
    <script src="historyTimelineGateWayAll.js"></script>
    <!--Schritt_5: jQuery einbinden-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#table_id').DataTable({

> I tried this way but it didnt work also

                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "gateWay_LIVE_UPDATE.php",
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "QUE" },
                    { "data": "FAILED" },
                    { "data": "TOTAL" },
                    { "data": "STATE" },
                ]
            });
            liveTimelineGateWayAll()
            historyTimelineGateWayAll()
            updateLiveGateWayAll_SQL_UPDATE()
            updateHistoryGateWayALL_SQL_INSERT()
        } );
    </script>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center">GATEWAY INFO TABLE</h1>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="getWayUpperPoint">GATEWAY</th>
        <th>QUE <br>(in Warteschlange)</th>
        <th>FAILED <br>(versenden Fehlgeschlagen Gesamt)</th>
        <th>TOTAL <br>(versendet Gesamt)</th>
        <th>STATE <br>(Status)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="gateWayUnderPoint">GATEWAY1</td>
        <td id="GTW_195_QUE"></td>
        <td id="GTW_195_FAILED"></td>
        <td id="GTW_195_TOTAL"></td>
        <td id="GTW_195_STATE"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gateWayUnderPoint">GATEWAY2</td>
        <td id="GTW_196_QUE"></td>
        <td id="GTW_196_FAILED"></td>
        <td id="GTW_196_TOTAL"></td>
        <td id="GTW_196_STATE"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gateWayUnderPoint">GATEWAY3</td>
        <td id="GTW_197_QUE"></td>
        <td id="GTW_197_FAILED"></td>
        <td id="GTW_197_TOTAL"></td>
        <td id="GTW_197_STATE"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gateWayUnderPoint">GATEWAY4</td>
        <td id="GTW_198_QUE"></td>
        <td id="GTW_198_FAILED"></td>
        <td id="GTW_198_TOTAL"></td>
        <td id="GTW_198_STATE"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--liveTimelineGateWayAll UND historyTimelineGateWayAll-->
<div class="hauptContainer">
    <div id="unterContainer1">
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <canvas id="myChartLive"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="unterContainer2">
        <br><br><br>
        <select class="selectContainer" id="select">
            <option class="styleSelect" value="none"></option>
            <option class="styleSelect" value="hours" selected >24 Stunden Verlauf</option>
            <option class="styleSelect" value="day">Wochenverlauf</option>
            <option class="styleSelect" value="week">Monatsverlauf</option>
        </select>
        <button class="selectContainer" type="button" onclick="historyTimelineGateWayAll()">Confirm</button>
        <canvas id="myChartHistory"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<!--liveTimelineGateWayAll UND historyTimelineGateWayAll-->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js" ></script>
<!--historyTimelineGateWayAll-->
<script src="historyTimelineGateWayAll.js"></script>
<script src="liveTimelineGateWayAll.js"></script>
<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post what is the response (JSON) from your `gateWay_LIVE_UPDATE.php`?

Comment: [{
 "QUE": "0",
 "FAILED": "0",
 "TOTAL": "3",
 "STATE": "UNKNOWN"
}, {
 "QUE": "0",
 "FAILED": "0",
 "TOTAL": "1",
 "STATE": "UNKNOWN"
}, {
 "QUE": "0",
 "FAILED": "0",
 "TOTAL": "12",
 "STATE": "UNKNOWN"
}, {
 "QUE": "0",
 "FAILED": "0",
 "TOTAL": "0",
 "STATE": "UNKNOWN"
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this snippet

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "data/objects_root_array.txt",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Source : [Flat array data source](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html)

Comment: yep thats it but the big point is when u convert a php array to json file u dont have "data" because of that u have to go that way at the converting->
    $ret = array(
        "data" => array($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4)
    );

    echo json_encode($ret);

Comment: one tiny problem is still, i want to use on of my table <td> tags as headliner but when u insert the datas into the columns that way it throws a error cause it will fill out the whole td tags with the datas which he receives from php